# parsing data sent from a spring controller

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send some datas from the controller to the jsp view then parse them using javascript to fill a table in html

this is the controller's method

```
final String SERVER_URI = "http://localhost:8081/BackEndFinalVersion";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/CourriersArrivées", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHome(Principal principal,Model model) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> roles = restTemplate
                .getForObject(SERVER_URI + "/getUserRole" + "?uid=" + principal.getName(), HashMap.class);
        List<String>r=(List<String>) roles.get("roles");
        for (int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++) {
            if(r.get(i).equals("Secrétaire Générale")){
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List<Map<String, Object>> allCourrier=  restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URI + "/listCourriersArrivés", ArrayList.class);
            System.out.println(allCourrier);
            model.addAttribute("allCourrier", allCourrier);

                return "CourriersArrivées";
            }
        }
        return "CreationCourrier";
    }
```

this controller will redirect me to "CreationCourrier.jsp page with the "allCourrier" attribute which is a `List<Map>` which gives me a result like this

```
[{date=19-5-5, expéditeur=Steg, listePiécesJointes=[C:\Users\Wassim\Downloads\eclipse\compte.txt, C:\Users\Wassim\Downloads\eclipse\udemy mdp.txt], isValidated=true, idCourrierArrivéFolder=workspace://SpacesStore/6cd81e2e-512f-47a1-a372-014369368584, départmentId=ROLE_ADMIN}, {date=19-5-5, expéditeur=Steg, listePiécesJointes=[C:\Users\Wassim\Downloads\eclipse\mdp enis account.txt, C:\Users\Wassim\Downloads\eclipse\udemy mdp.txt], isValidated=true, idCourrierArrivéFolder=workspace://SpacesStore/68afae4e-195f-4d58-8d0d-3b3525b0edeb, départmentId=ROLE_ADMIN}
```

which is very hard to parse because it is not json so I can't parse him easily with javascript 
My question is that is there any easy way to parse this result and if not can you show me how to send json format for exemple which is easier to parse

Comment: Your question its confuse for me, if you are sending data to one JSP file, you can just work with the list and populate the table, if you are talking about JSON could be also because you are doing an AJAX call and need to update the table results, which its the case?

Comment: My question is about wich is the best way of them in my case

Comment: Use JSP and the spring tags to render your table then

Comment: can u give me an exemple of how to parse this list to generate an html table

Comment: First i would translate the rest result to some internal object, lets call it Courier, then in your jsp you could use c:forEach tag to go over all Couriers and render the values you need